# How to iterate on a folder located outside a .jar file running

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, jar

I have a problem with my java app architecture. I want to deliver a simple .jar file generated with Spring Boot. I need to iterate over files presents in another folder, after running the .jar.
Here is the hierarchy of my directory:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z03b.png)

1. I launch my .jar with a .bat or sh, with java -jar myApp.jar
2. I have to iterate on all files that are present in myApp/files

it seems simple but I can't find a way to do this !  I try a lot of things found here but nothing works !

I try this but had a nullPointer...

```
File jarFile = new File(myMainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
        String jarLocation = jarFile.getPath();
```

Could you help me please with some try to do !

Thanks !

Comment: Find out when you get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your .bat file to start into your myApp folder like this

```
@echo off

#do stuff

cd %myApp_folder%

java -jar myapp.jar
```

and you can resolve your folders via relative path like this:

```
File confFolder = new File("conf");
File filesFolder = new File("files");
```